# How would one go about finding all the solutions to $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {457^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to find all the solutions to $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {457^2}$. Would Tonelli's Algorithm be the best way to go about doing this? I'm trying to think of other ways to solve this...

Thanks!

Comment: First solve $x^2\equiv 2(\text{mod } 457)$ by using quadratic reciprocity.  Note that any solution of $x^2\equiv 2(\text{mod } 457^2)$ must be a solution of $x^2\equiv 2(\text{mod } 457)$

Comment: By quadratic reciprocity... Doing that, we show that $2 \in QR_{457}$, so there exist $x$ such that $457 \equiv x^2 \pmod 2$?

Comment: The answer is $\big\{80969,127880\big\}$.